# In python, If I perform an fft on complex data, then irfft only the positive frequencies, how does that affect the data?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, ifft

So I am trying to perform a frequency shift on a set of real valued points.  In order to achieve a frequency shift, one has to multiply the data by a complex exponential, making the resulting data complex. If I multiply by just a cosine I get results at both the sum and difference frequencies. I want just the sum or the difference.

What I have done is multiply the data by a complex exponential, use fft.fft() to compute the fft, then used fft.irfft() on only the positive frequencies to obtain a real valued dataset that has only a sum or difference shift in frequency. This seems to work great, but I want to know if there are any cons to doing this, or maybe a more appropriate way of accomplishing the same goal. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Not really a problem. The FFT of real data is redundant in the spectral domain (has to be , you put only N values in, 2N values can not be dependent) Leaving out the negative frequencies does not remove information, unless you apply a different treatment to those negatives and want to keep the info. I keep all frequencies before IFFT, but you don't have to.

Comment: @reoadrunner66 But it is not the FFT of real data. I have multiplied the real data by a complex number(s) which makes it _complex_ data. I then take the full FFT in which the negative frequencies are not necessarily redundant. I then feed only the positive frequencies of that into IRFFT at which point the IRFFT function assumes the negative frequencies are conjugates of the positives, hence redundant, when they are _not_ in general.

Comment: If you multiply by only one complex number (a fixed phase) then you shouldn't increase the information content. But one would have to look at the analytical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine.  You are generating the analytic signal to accommodate the negative frequencies in the same way a discrete Hilbert transform would.  You will have some scaling issues - you need to double all the non-DC and non-Nyquist signals in the real frequency portion of the FFT results.

Some practical concerns are that this method imparts a delay of the window size, so if you are trying to do this in real-time you should probably examine using a FIR Hilbert transformer and the appropriate sums.  The delay will be the group delay of the Hilbert transformer in that case.

Another item of concern is that you need to remember that the DC component of your signal will also shift along with all the other frequencies.  As such I would recommend that you demean the data (save the value) before shifting, zero out the DC bin after you FFT the data (to remove whatever frequency component ended up in the DC bin), then add the mean back to preserve the signal levels at the end.

Comment: Awesome! I was worried to was too good to be true. As far as the scaling, are you sure about the factor of two in the real frequencies? To my understanding, rfft/irfft do the same computation and just assume that the negative frequencies are conjugate to the positive ones and as such returns   positive frequencies/real values accordingly.

Comment: As far as the delay, it is a time delay equal to the window size of my fft? The Hilbert transformer is meant to counteract it? Also, is the DC component important if you do not need the absolute amplitudes, i.e. if you are just going to demodulate an RF signal?

Comment: You are throwing away half your energy if you only keep the positive frequencies. So the factor 2 is right. As I said earlier you are not throwing away information. Just do the analytical FFT of a real signal, split into cosine and sine parts, apply the symmetries rules (cosine symmetric, sine antisymmetric) and you can prove why you are fine, doing what your are doing.

Comment: The DC becomes a tone at f0 when you shift everything by f0.  If you do not want any new tones, then you must demean the signal before multiplying by exp(jwt).